# MailX sending all mails to spam folder

Tags: postfix, centos6, email

I followed the setup as instructed in this link:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-postfix-on-centos-6

I successfully installed everything and mail is being sent via

mail myemail@gmail.com
Subject: Test Subject
Test
.
EOT

But all mails are being sent to the spam folder. Any ideas on how to fix this? TIA

Comment: Do not use 'spam words' like `test` in email subject and body.

Answer (score 3):

1. [Set up DNS SPF records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784415/how-to-properly-set-up-dns-spf-records) and enable DKIM on the server.
2. Check your IP address here http://spamhaus.org/

added: 
3. Set up [PTR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) (reverse DNS) for your IP address.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use your ISP's relay server.  This should get you around many of the host checks.

If you want to send directly you will need a static IP address.  Get your DNS configured so that rDNS validatation passes.  (Your IP provider will need to configure a PTR record for you.)

If you have your own domain, configure an [SPF](http://www.openspf.org/) record allowing your ISP's relay server to send mail for your domain.  Using [DKIM](http://www.dkim.org/) with 1024 or 2048 bit key, should help as well.

If you configure SPF and DKIM, you can add [DMARC](http://www.dmarc.org) to your configuration.  This will enable you to get you a delivery report, and/or a failure report on mail to sent supporting servers.